# Visual Studio code cleanup - where is configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-cleanup

When I open Configure Code Cleanup in VS 2019, there are entries like "Apply expression/block body preferences".

Where are those "preferences"? How can I configure this tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Options dialog box, select Text Editor > [C# or Basic] > Code Style > General.